# What is the most general mathematical structure for representing a state in QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, density-operator, quantum-states, foundations

In quantum mechanics textbooks which are a little more careful it is common to see it noted that a (pure) quantum state is not a vector $|\psi\rangle$ but rather a ray in Hilbert space, $c|\psi\rangle$ (for all $c \in \mathbb{C}$). Obviously, the axiom giving the probabilities for different measurements of different observables must be generalized to include a denominator which normalizes things.

In other (even more careful?) quantum mechanics textbooks (see e.g. the start of Chapter 2 of Ballentine's *Quantum Mechanics: A Modern Development*) it's noted that a state is to be represented by an operator $\rho$ which is a valid state as long as $\rho$ is nonnegative, of unit trace, and self-adjoint. This generalized definition works since the identification of pure states $\psi$ with $\rho = | \psi \rangle \langle \psi|$ allows for an isomorphic development of the theory. My question is: Is it valid, as in the pure state case noted above, to generalize the statement about $\rho$ above and to say that all operators $\rho'$ which are nonnegative and self-adjoint represent valid states, with the observation that every such $\rho'$ is related to a unique $\rho$ of unit trace by $\rho' = c\rho$ for some $c \in \mathbb{C}$. The axiom for averages of observables (which is enough to in turn obtain probability distributions as does Ballentine in Chap 2, if we make assumptions about functions of operators) is modified to something like, for an observable $R$, $\langle R \rangle = \textrm{Tr}(R\rho')/\textrm{Tr}(\rho')$ (and that we would recover the same results since $\textrm{Tr}(R\rho')/\textrm{Tr}(\rho') = \textrm{Tr}(Rc\rho)/\textrm{Tr}(c\rho) = c\textrm{Tr}(R\rho)/c\textrm{Tr}(\rho) = \textrm{Tr}(R\rho) $ for that corresponding unit trace operator $\rho$)?

Edit: As noted by J. Murray, the $c$ I mention should be positive (and real) so that all $\rho'$ remain nonnegative.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you'd want to do this?

Comment: @J.Murray No, but in the same sense is there a particular reason we need to say that a quantum state is a ray in Hilbert space rather than saying that it's a normalized vector with zero phase? I say this not to be sarcastic but to suggest my motivation for asking the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see any motivation for this.  The standard model of quantum mechanics loosely works by modeling the state of a quantum mechanical system as an element of the underlying Hilbert space, and then computing dynamics via the Schrodinger equation.

As you say, a more careful treatment would note that in terms of physical content, $\psi$ and $c\psi$ for any nonzero $c\in \mathbb C$ represent precisely the same physical state.  This identification is important, because otherwise there would be no possible way to decide how to model a system.  Say a spin-1/2 system is prepared in the spin-up state.  Is the initial state vector of the system given by $\pmatrix{1\\0}$ or $\pmatrix{-1\\0}$? Or maybe $\pmatrix{i\\0}$?  The identification of all these vectors as representatives of the same physical state means that it doesn't matter - we can freely choose any of them.

As you say, though, this is insufficiently general because we'd like to allow "classical" statistical mixtures of such states.  In an ensemble of pure states $|\psi_i\rangle$ with probabilites $p_i$, the appropriate choice is to use a density operator
$$\rho = \sum_i p_i |\psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_i|$$
and the generalized rule $\langle A\rangle = \mathrm{Tr}(A\rho)$. We can define the set of all such $\rho$'s without reference to pure states by requiring that they be positive, trace-class operators with unit trace.

Your proposal is to enlarge the space of possible states by allowing them to be scaled by some nonnegative real number, but I don't see a reason to do so. The identification of physical states with rays in the Hilbert space is natural because vectors which are multiples of one another have the same physical content. The generalization to mixed states allows for statistical ensembles of pure states. The generalization to scaled density operators isn't physically necessary (in some sense it is the opposite of the identification $\psi \sim c\psi$) and doesn't actually get us anything useful.

---

Lastly, there *is* actually a further generalization if one adopts the algebraic formulation of quantum mechanics; in this picture, a state is given by a positive, normalized linear functional on a $C^*$ algebra, but this is much more technical and not particularly common.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. First of all thank you for noting that $c$ would need to be a nonnegative real in my construction; I clearly made a mistake there. I guess part of my misunderstanding is arises from your statement that, without the “ray consideration”, we wouldn’t know whether the states you mention are different. But in the same vein, couldn’t we say as part of the axiom that we always take the first option you gave (just as you suggest that the axiom be that we always take unit trace density operator)?

Comment: @EE18 Perhaps a better example would be if we prepared the state to be spin-down along the $x$-axis, in which case we'd have to choose between $\pmatrix{1\\-1}$ and $\pmatrix{-1\\1}$.  The point is that when we talk about physical states, we're usually talking about *distinguishable* configurations of the system. If two states have exactly the same physical properties in every way, then we would say that they are in fact one and the same. As a result, $\psi$ and $c\psi$ are distinct elements of the Hilbert space, but represent the same physical state of the system.

Comment: I think I perhaps see the distinction now. In what you describe, we are already restricting states to those that are normalized, and then you mention that because it would be difficult to pick out one among the many (related by a phase) normalized vector, we consider them all the state. In my case, the restriction of normalization specifies a single vector since $c$ must be real. Is that understanding correct? And asking now just in theory, is the construction I give at least mathematically correct, if not useful?

Comment: @EE18 Not quite. I'm saying that we might naively think that physical states are in one-to-one correspondence with (nonzero) elements of the Hilbert space, but it's easy to prove that if $\psi$ and $c\psi$ produce the same predictions in every circumstance which *forces* us to recognize them as representing the same state. Distinguishing them is merely difficult, it's impossible. Your suggestion is the opposite - given the set of density operators, your proposal is to *expand* the set of states to include non-normalized ones, each of which is equivalent to exactly one of the normalized states.

Comment: @EE18 and J. Murray Hannabuss defines states as (normalized positive linear functionals on a *-algebra), but then at the end, he remarks that "Even this algebraic formulation of quantum theory is not the most general. Some physical observables, such as times when a photon hits a counter, cannot be easily be interpreted as elements of the algebra, and for them there are still more general approaches." Ref: Keith Hannabuss _An Introduction to Quantum Theory_pp. 196--199.